# Backbone events firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events, event-bubbling

I'm using Backbone together with require.js and jQuery.
What I'm trying to do is to simply bind an event to a container which should show (mouseover) or hide (mouseout) a video. The event fires but unfortunately too many times (I've several children inside `.intro-content`). I tried using `ev.stopPropagation()` (as seen in the code) and `ev.stopImmediatePropagation` but this doesn't prevent the bubbling. What am I doing wrong?

View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'global'
], function($, _, Backbone, Global){

    var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#splitlayout'),

        events: {
            'mouseover .side-left .intro-content': 'checkVideoState',
            'mouseout .side-left .intro-content': 'checkVideoState'
        },        

        render: function(){

            this.playVideo('video', '0GsrOOV0gQM');
            this.delegateEvents();

        },

        initialize: function() {

            _.bindAll(this);
            this.render();

        },

        checkVideoState: function(ev) {

            ev.stopPropagation();

            if(!$('#video').hasClass('active') && ev.type == 'mouseover') {

                this.showVideo();

            } else if($('#video').hasClass('active') && ev.type == 'mouseout') {

                this.hideVideo();

            }

        },

        showVideo: function() {
            console.log('test');
            $('#video').addClass('active');
            player.playVideo();
        },

        hideVideo: function() {
            console.log('test');
            $('#video').removeClass('active');
            player.pauseVideo();
        },

        playVideo: function(container, videoId) {

            var self = this;

            if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
                    self.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
                };

                $.getScript('//www.youtube.com/iframe_api');
            } else {
                self.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
            }

        },

        loadPlayer: function(container, videoId) {

            player = new YT.Player(container, {
                videoId: videoId,
                playerVars: {
                    controls: 0,
                    loop: 1,
                    modestbranding: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                    showinfo: 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': this.onPlayerReady
                }
            });

        },

        onPlayerReady: function() {

            player.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
            player.seekTo(8,false);
            player.pauseVideo();

        }

    });

    return VideoView;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably initialized your view twice.

Here is an example of double events http://jsfiddle.net/rph4R which you can fix with removing last line `new VideoView();`.

To check this you may add

```
console.log('initialize');
```

to the `VideoView.initialize()` method and check on console or use `debugger` or `console.trace()` to see full call stack.

You can also check search for this code in your files and count it

```
new VideoView();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the event multiple times because you have multiple children in your container.  Every time the mouse moves over a new child in the container a new event will be triggered.  Basically, you want to use `mouseenter` instead.  Have a look at the example at the bottom of the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but mouseenter and mouseleave do also fire the events multiple times..

Comment: @enyce12 please make sure you didn't initialize your view twice here is an example of double events http://jsfiddle.net/rph4R/ you can fix it with removing last line `new VideoView();`. To check this you may add `console.log('initialize')` to the `initialize` method and check console.

Comment: @EugeneGlova That was it... I initialized it in a Router and another View. Thank you! Could you add that hint to your answer?